# how to get browsed pdf file path in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

When I select a PDF file through local browse I want its path also.

```
 onChangeFile(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var file =URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(file);
        this.setState({file}); /// if you want to upload latter
    }

 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row" style={{marginLeft: '8%'}}>
                    <input id="myInput" type="file" onChange={this.onChangeFile.bind(this)}
                        accept="application/pdf" ref={(ref) => this.myInput = ref} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
                        <button className="buttonPop" onClick={(e) => this.myInput.click() }>Change</button>
                    </div>
```

I only get the doc name, doc modified time. I want to get the path of  the document that I selected

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the path from a file input; the browser will not let you access it due to security reasons.